# Mysql query - grouping results

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have 2 tables and basically what I like to do is group the results or counts together for display. Tried different version of mysql statement but not getting anywhere.

The 2 example tables are:

```
tbl_One  
index   O_priority
1         low
2         medium
3         high   

tbl_Two 
t_priority
2
1
3
3
2
3
1
1
1

expected results:
low =  4
medium =  2
high = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T1.O_priority,T2.c FROM tbl_One as T1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(*) as c,t_priority FROM tbl_Two GROUP BY t_priority) as T2 ON T1.index = T2.t_priority;
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables, then group the results:

```
SELECT   tbl_One.O_priority, COUNT(*)
FROM     tbl_One JOIN tbl_Two ON tbl_Two.t_priority = tbl_One.index
GROUP BY tbl_One.index
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acc6f/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

Simple as much as you can, try this:

```
SELECT count(o.index) as `index`, o.O_priority 
FROM tbl_One o join tbl_two t on t.t_priority = o.index
group by t.t_priority;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6c6d/6/0)